# BlogEngine .Net on load balanced two servers and one database

Tags: memcached, load-balancing, blogengine.net

I am to use Blogengine .Net as my blogengine and most of it served well until I realized I have to run this identically on two servers and one database.

When the editor is on server 1, anything he/she posts will be written to the database and will be updated in the in memory post list(static List Posts). Meantime for any user on server 2, nothing done on server 1 is visible because the in memory post there won't be updated.

One life questioning solution is making the editor switch servers from their host files and with a help of a shinny button making them able to reload the posts as

```
BlogEngine.Core.Post.Reload();
HttpRuntime.Close();
```

but I really feel there should be a better solution because I m now thinking about would integrating Memcached somewhere here be easy, if not I guess I have to switch from BlogEngine .Net.

Any suggestion would be more than welcome,

Thanks,
Bilsay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem. I am running 2 servers and a load balancer to do the work. I first login with the first server, and post the blog. than login on the second server and press the button "reset cache" which I wrote to get the data again from database. But this solution is still troublesome for user comments. 
Thanks

Comment: Sounds like there should be another clean way but nice workaround. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's an extension to help solve this problem: 
http://allben.net/post/2009/05/10/Web-Farm-Extension-10